# Windows loader problem - turn on verbose mode

Tags: windows, linker, loader

I'm in the process of reorganizing some of the legacy libraries in our application which 
has unmanaged code calling into libraries of managed code.  While I have the code
reorganized, it produces the following loader error:

```
 
...
'app.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\CsDisp.dll'
'app.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\psapi.dll'
'app.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll'
'app.exe': Loaded 'C:\appCode\Debug\daq206_32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'app.exe': Loaded 'C:\appCode\Debug\SiUSBXp.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'app.exe': Loaded 'C:\appCode\Debug\AdlinkDAQ.dll', Symbols loaded.
'app.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\P9842.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
LDR: LdrRelocateImageWithBias() failed 0xc0000018
LDR: OldBase     : 10000000
LDR: NewBase     : 00A80000
LDR: Diff        : 0x7c90d6fa0012f6cc
LDR: NextOffset  : 00000000
LDR: *NextOffset : 0x0
LDR: SizeOfBlock : 0xa80000
Debugger:: An unhandled non-continuable exception was thrown during process load
```

I believe 0xc0000018 error is an overlapping address range.  So, I have two questions.  First, what linker options may cause this error?  I'm currently linking with /DYNAMICBASE:NO and /FIXED:No as this was how some of the previous libraries were set up.
Second, is there a way to turn on verbose mode for the loader so I can see what exactly it's trying to load?  P9842 is a third party library so I imagine it is getting to one of my libraries after P9842 and failing on that one.  Can I narrow it down?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about the first question.  A search for that status code [hit this article with the interesting note](http://ntsecurity.nu/onmymind/2006/2006-06-01.html) that "Before XP there was no check in Windows for page mappings with different memory types. Windows XP does check though. A second memory type mapping attempt will fail with the STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES (0xc0000018) error message."  Might be relevant if you are using MapViewOfFile...

For the second question, you want to see loader snaps.  See [this article at msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/hood/hood0999.aspx).  This command should help: 
"gflags -i yourApp.exe +sls"

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It did get me past this error and on to an Access Violation (my lucky day :-).  The article on loader snaps was better than others that I came across.